# Python: CRC implementation using xor and shift registers

Tags: python, hardware, xor, crc

I was trying to implement 5-bit CRC with the CRC generator 100101.
However, this code doesn't reflect the hardware Xor and shift registers in CRC;
On the hardware level, we have the following :

[image]

How can this be implemented on python?

As a clarification, I was wondering if there is some code that deals with bit-wise xor and shift operators << as an approach to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking -- you code looks fine so far and, as you state, it gives the correct results.

I may point you to the [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) data structure in the Standard Library which I find quite useful to represent shift registers because it provides the `rotate()` method to do exactly this kind of circular shift.

This code give the same results as your code:

```
from collections import deque

deque_crc = deque([0,0,0,0,0],maxlen=5)

myID.extend(deque_crc)

for x in myID:
    deque_crc.rotate(-1)
    deque_crc[2] = (deque_crc[2] + deque_crc[4]) % 2
    deque_crc[4] = (deque_crc[4] + x) % 2

myID[-5:] = deque_crc

print myID
```

EDIT:

Since you are asking for a bitwise implementation of the algorithm you might want to checkout these sources:

- http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation
- [bitstring module](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! As a clarification, I was wondering if there is some code that deals with bit-wise xor and shift operators << as an approach to solve this. but then i guess i cant deal with lists i think. (New to python)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to really use CRC code (as opposed to studying their implementation) you may find the [Python crcmod](http://crcmod.sourceforge.net/) Module very useful. I have been using it for years and it is very easy to use. Just throw in the polynomial and get a CRC function ready to process your data.

It may however not support 5bit CRC polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this code doesn't reflect the hardware Xor and shift registers in CRC;

It does!

This:

```
CRC[0] = CRC[1]
CRC[1] = CRC[2]
CRC[2] = CRC[3]
CRC[3] = CRC[4]
CRC[4] = input
```

*is* a model of a shift register.

The `(Something+1) %2` is one way of representing the XOR operation.

I would argue you have pretty accurately modelled the diagram you show!